# What is wrong with my code - "Run-time error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: vba, excel, object, runtime-error

Can you please check what am I missing in my code? 
When it reaches at `wrd.Visible = True`, it gives me error "Run-time error 91 : Object variable or With block variable not set".

I have already activated the Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library

[image: OBL SS]

```
Sub Exceltoword_template()
'Declares and set w as active worksheet
Dim w As Worksheet
Set w = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Declaration for word app
Dim wrd As Object
Dim worddoc As Word.Document

'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
'Is MS Word already opened?
'      Set wrd = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
      Set wrd = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear
'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If wrd Is Nothing Then Set wrd = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
'     Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

On Error GoTo 0
'Make MS Word Visible and Active

wrd.Visible = True
wrd.Activate


EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That error must be coming from somewhere else - the code is functional providing you have Word 2010 installed.

Comment: Is the error number higher than zero before you ask for number 429?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes, I'm using 2010 version.

Comment: This may not help (as it could be just syntax semantacs), but what happens if you write; `Set wrd = GetObject(,"Word.Application")`? Also maybe `Set wrd = Word.Application` (since you are using early binding). Also, this statement: `Err.Clear` will not allow this statement: `If Err.Number` to execute, since `Err.Number` clears the error (and sets number back to 0).

Comment: Your code is working for me (Win XP, MS Word 11.0 Object Library). I know, a bit old....

Comment: @CMArg it was working for me too yesterday but not today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd generally advise against using early binding, although it can help with the intellisense.  I could get the same error as you by omitting the word `Set` when referencing Word but other than that it worked fine.

Try this code; it doesn't need a reference to Word:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oWD As Object
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Be precise, don't trust to Active or Selection.
    Set oWD = CreateWD

    Set oDoc = oWD.Documents.Add 'Create a new document.
    'Set oDoc = oWD.ActiveDocument
    'Set oDoc = oWD.Documents("My Document.docx")
    'Set oDoc = oWD.Windows("My Document.docx [Compatibility Mode]") '- As it appears on the title bar of the document.

    With oDoc
        'Coding for Word
    End With

End Sub

Public Function CreateWD(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpWD As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Word is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpWD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Word. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    oTmpWD.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateWD = oTmpWD

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateWD."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I need it slightly changed. Please help me. How do I change the code `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents.Add` to `Set oDoc` as active document as my word doc is already open. Is there a way to control or get access by the doc's title?

Comment: I tried using `Set oDoc = oWD.ActiveDocument`. it doesnt work for the file which is already open and give me error **This command is not available because no document is open.** However, when I add a document using code `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents.Add`, it then detects the active document.

Comment: I've added commented code to show how to assign `oDoc`.

Comment: I've no idea why `Set oDoc = oWD.ActiveDocument` didn't work if it was already open unless you have two instances of Word open and it's referencing the wrong one?

Comment: I also tried opening the file with code `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents("I:\Documents\Sample Stage 3 for EUC-updated.docx").Open` but it says **Bad File Name**

Comment: I tried checking the open instances of word by using `Set oDoc = Word.ActiveDocument` but it says **Run-time error 4248:This command is not available because no document is open.** while my file is already open.

Comment: Try `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents("Sample Stage 3 for EUC-updated.docx")` if the file is already open or `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents.Open("I:\Documents\Sample Stage 3 for EUC-updated.docx")` if it isn't.

Comment: So File is already open and I used `Set oDoc = oWD.Documents("Sample Stage 3 for EUC-updated.docx")` but it says **Run-time Error 4160 | Bad File Name.**

Comment: Okay, I noticed something. Though it's not recognizing the file which is already open but it's creating a new instance of word(with no doc). When I closed my file and opened the file within the instance created by VBA, I'm able to detect the file. why is the VBA creating new instance every time I run it.

Comment: It shouldn't be.  This line of code should set the reference to an existing instance of Word:  `GetObject(, "Word.Application")`.

Comment: I am able to get through a workaround using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)`. It will fail opening the file at the first attempt but will go through starting second.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as reference. It's very similar code I use to open check for Outlook and mirrors your intention exactly, only it simplifies it much more.

```
'requires early binding (reference set for Microsoft Word Object Library)
'first check if outlook is running and if not open it
Dim wdApp As Word.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If wdApp Is Nothing Then Set wdApp = New Word.Application
```

I have been using this for years without failure.